# images in spring mvc jsp file

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I've been learning and trying to use Spring MVC to develop web applications. I'm trying to use images from /WebContent/resources/images in my jsp files. While I can successfully use images in my jsp file using (c:url) format, I cannot seem to find a way to use these images in my css files. I've tried several paths, but none of them seem to work.`:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc= "http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
  <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/"> </mvc:resources>
```

JSP file down below:

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Auto-Info</title>
<link  rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/auto.css" />">
</head>
<body>
   <div class="contain">
   <header>
   <h1><a href="#">AUTO INFO</a></h1>
   </header>
   <nav>
  <ul> 
  <li><a href="" target="_self">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="login" target="_self">LOGIN</a></li>
  <li><a href="register" target="_self">REGISTER</a></li>
  </ul>
   </nav>
     <div class="carsec">
    <form action="" method="get">
    <input list="Make" name="Make">
        <datalist id="Make" name="Make" class="displist">
        <option value="Ford"> Ford</option> 
           <option value="Chevrolet"> Chevrolet</option> 
            <option value="Kia">Kia</option> 
            <option value="Maserati">Maserati</option> 
            <option value="Nissan"> Nissan</option> 
            <option value="Honda">Honda</option> 
            <option value="Tesla">Tesla</option> 
            <option value="Toyota">Toyota</option> 
              <option value="Subaru">Subaru</option> 
              <option value="Volkswagen">Volkswagen</option> 
              <option value="Hyundai">Hyundai</option> 
        </datalist>
         <input list="Year">
        <datalist id="Year" name="Year" class="displist">
           <option value="2005"> 2005</option> 
            <option value="2007">2007</option> 
            <option value="2009"> 2009</option> 
            <option value="2010">2010</option> 
               <option value="2011">2011</option> 
            <option value="2012">2012</option> 
            <option value="2013">2013</option> 
            <option value="2014">2014</option> 
            <option value="2015">2015</option> 
            <option value="2016">2016</option> 

        </datalist>
         </form>

    </div>
     <img alt="auto" src="<c:url value="/resources/imgs/Optimized-maxresdefault.jpg" />" style="width:400px; height:250px;" >
   <div class="tables">
    <table> 
        <tr>
        <th> <b>Make </b></th>
        <th> <b>Model</b> </th>
        <th> <b>VIN </b></th>
        <th> <b>Year</b> </th>
        </tr>
         <c:forEach items="${vehicles}" var="vehicle">
        <tr>
            <td>${vehicle.make}</td>
            <td>${vehicle.model}</td>
            <td>${vehicle.VIN}</td>
        <td>${vehicle.year}</td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Found  Solution:

```
    background: url("http://localhost:8080/SpringMysql/resources/imgs/Optimized-maxresdefault.jpg"):

     background: url("/SpringMysql/resources/imgs/Optimized-maxresdefault.jpg")
```

Both of them  work fine. The second option might be the right choice.
P.s: SpringMysql is the name of my project and I had to remove /WebContent/ from the file path to get it to work.

Comment: Show your HTML code also and update the question.

Comment: done @AtaurRahmanMunna.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `dispatcher-servlet` map your resource url like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/**"> </mvc:resources>
```

and in your jsp page img source be like

```
<img alt="auto" src="<c:url value='/resources/imgs/Optimized-maxresdefault.jpg' />" style="width:400px; height:250px;" >
```

and let me know the status.

**UPDATE:**
Suppose your css folder and images folder are reside in resources folder.

```
resources
   |_ images
   |_ css
```

For accessing images from css file you can use relative path like this:

```
background-image: url(../images/your_image_file_name.jpg);
```

Comment: Hey Rahman, I can access images using the <c:url> format in my jsp files. I was requesting help with using the images in css files etc, where I cannot use the 'c:' tags and all the different, filepaths I've tried do not seem to work.

Comment: @Rahman I've used the same path that worked with <c:url> for my background property in css, but did not work. I've also tried all  different variations of the paths, but still couldn't get it to work. Had to resort to using <div> elements to style the images at the end.

Comment: Got it to work.
I have used :

        background: url("http://localhost:8080/SpringMysql/resources/imgs/Optimizedmaxresdefault.jpg");

Comment: you should know that JSTL compiles in server side. so if you put same code in css,it will not work.

Comment: @yashwanthnemani, what happen when you deployed your application to another server with different port? did planing to change all of your css code before deployment?

Comment: Say for example you have setup a new server which ip: `192.168.103.11` and your tomcat running on `8003` port. then how can you load those images?

Comment: @Rahman, I have made changes to the question. Though, I do not have enough knowledge to answer your questions, maybe you can help me figure out a permanent solution based on the temporary solution I have found, Thanks.

Comment: When your css file loaded, if you linked your image in the css, then also the image loaded.open your browser console and click `'net'` and follow my answer and see why the image didn't loaded.